# Merge two Bitmaps

Tags: android, bitmap, merge, transparent

I like to merge two same sized Bitmaps in my Application.
The first Bitmap has a "hud" with mainly black background.
The second Bitmap is a Picture of a person.
I like to put the "hud" over the second picture.

Now my question: Should I first make the black pixels of the first image transparent and then somehow combine these pictures, or is there an algorithm which ignores the black pixels of the first picture and takes the pixels of the second one?

Comment: No, the hud needs a transparent background. Than you can simply combine the two bitmaps in a `LayerList`.

Comment: do you have a link to a solution where I can select black pixels and make them transparent?

Comment: The solution is called Photoshop - or a similar photo editing software. You have to prepare your images for your app not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which works:

```
public Bitmap createTransparentBitmapFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,
        int replaceThisColor) {
    if (bitmap != null) {
        int picw = bitmap.getWidth();
        int pich = bitmap.getHeight();
        int[] pix = new int[picw * pich];
        bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, picw, 0, 0, picw, pich);

        for (int y = 0; y < pich; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < picw; x++) {
                int index = y * picw + x;

                if (pix[index] == replaceThisColor) {
                    pix[index] = Color.TRANSPARENT;
                }
            }
        }
        Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(pix, picw, pich,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        return bm;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Save this now transparent Bitmap as png:

```
public void savePicture(Bitmap b1, String description, int instrCounter) {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
            + "/BrushGuide";
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(path, description + instrCounter + ".PNG");
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        b1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (Throwable ignore) {
        }
    }

}
```

Merge this png picture with another one saved on sd card:

```
public Bitmap mergePictures() {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1100, 650, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Drawable drawable1 = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
           .toString() + "/myfolder/photo.png"));
        Drawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
           .toString() + "/myfolder/hud.png"));

        drawable1.setBounds(0, 0, 1100, 650);
        drawable2.setBounds(0, 0, 1100, 650);
        drawable1.draw(c);
        drawable2.draw(c);

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return bitmap;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Transparency is the way to go.  Everything in the HUD is zero alpha channel where you want it to show the underlying picture below your HUD. Only those pixels in the HUD that show something have a non-zero alpha.  That way, when you combine the two images together you don't need any pixel by pixel logic - simply add pixels

Answer (score 0):

The hud needs a transparent background. After that you can combine the two bitmaps with a `LayerList`. Create an xml file in the folder res/drawable and put this in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/person" />
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/hud" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

You can than refer to the combined drawable like this: `R.drawable.name_of_xml_file`.